# Wordpress: User registration - check mail if it exists in external api

Tags: wordpress

Is there a way to verify that there is an email entered in a registration form (ultimate member) and when registering or writing the email, a function that makes a request to an API with the email and verifies that it exists, if it exists it lets you register but if it does not exist you can not register?

Thank you very much for your support.

Comment: By "email exists" do you mean the email address is real or that your database has a record of it?

Comment: I am very sorry and thank you for your answer, I forgot to clarify it is for an external API.

Answer (score -1):

use this filter to get a user email after auth:

```
add_filter('wp_authenticate_user','func_auth_signon',10,2);
function func_auth_signon($user, $password) {
    if ( is_a( $user, 'WP_User' ) {
        $email = $user->user_email;
        //check if email exist in API
        if(!is_email_exist($email))
        //else logout user
        wp_logout();
    }
    return $user;
}
```

**Check if email of user exist in api**

```
function is_email_exist($email){
  $url = 'YOUR API URL'
  $ch = curl_init($url);
  // Set the result output to be a string.
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
 
  $data = curl_exec($ch);

  if(curl_error($ch)) {
    return false;
   }
  curl_close($ch);
  if($data) return true;
  return false;

}
```

Comment: I am very sorry and thank you for your answer, I forgot to clarify it is for an external API.

Comment: It does not matter, you can make a regular connection and compare it with an external api

Comment: Thanks for your help, how do I make the connection to the api, this is new to me, I'm desperate. thank you very much.

Comment: @JoseRodriguezDuran I add function to connect to api, bs"d